# Performing a routine upon filename change

Tags: sharepoint

I am new to sharepoint and am looking for a way to perform this:

- I have a folder A which is private
- I have a folder A2 which belongs to another user
- In folder A i put files. Lets call them File1
- Whenever I am happy with the contents of File1, I can safely share it. Sharing is done by copying it to folder A2.

I have automated this before under a Synology NAS by prepending a # symbol to the filename. So whenever system detects a filename change form File1 to #File1, it creates a copy in A2.

Is there a mechanism under SharePoint that allows me to do this by monitoring filename changes and triggering some kind of event I can process programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In Sharepoint, we have ItemUpdated event receiver.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using SharePoint Designer workflows. We typically add a status column to trigger the move instead of a special symbol in the filename. Either could be done with a workflow. Unlike an event receiver, there is no custom code, and the workflow can be created in all versions of SharePoint, even SharePoint Online / O365.

Just create a workflow that starts on item Changed. Let it check the status of the Status column or the special symbol in the name, and either just exit, or perform the move.